# Access Macro - Was textbox changed from default value?

Tags: vba, ms-access, controls

I have an Access form with textboxes that contain some default text. The users are required to replace the text with words of their own, so I wrote a macro to confirm that (before proceeding to the next record) the text boxes no longer contain the default text. (It gives user a warning plus some other tasks, which is why I'm not using built-in Validation rules.)

The macro contains this sequence:

```
SetLocalVar
Name: booDetailDefault
Expression = [Forms]![frmChangeReq]![txtProblem].[Text]=[Forms]![frmChangeReq]![txtProblem].[DefaultValue]
```

The idea is if `...[Text]` is the same as `...[DefaultValue]`, then `booDetailDefault` would be TRUE, and if not, FALSE.

However, what I *do* get is "Type Mismatch". I would think that Text and DefaultValue would be the same type.

1. Can you tell why I got this error?
2. Is there any way to display the Text and DefaultValue values so I can see why Access thinks they're different?
3. Is there a better way to see if the text boxes have been changed?

EDIT: The default text is set in the Property Sheet for the textbox. I've been running it manually, not tying it to an event yet, until I get it working.

I used Text instead of Value because that's what was available in the Macro Builder, but just in case I tried changing it to Value. It works, although I have to tell the expression to expect quotation marks around half of it:

```
[Forms]![frmChangeReq]![txtProblem].[DefaultValue]="""" & [Forms]![frmChangeReq]![txtProblem].[Value] & """"
```

Comment: (Been a while since I did this so I might be off...) Where do you set the default text? Table, form, code?

Comment: What event is macro in? Probably should use Value instead of Text. Suggest using VBA instead of macro. Easier to debug.